# Spring security Authorize Requests value from database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to configure Authorize Requests value from database on server start up. Currently I am giving hard core value in Java class file, is there any way to read the same from database.

Below is the sample code:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .authorizeRequests()                                                                
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            
        .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
        .and()
    // ...
    .formLogin();
}
```

How to read url from database for eg : /admin/** from database instead of hard code value in class files

Comment: and what will be the desired outcome if the database is not accessible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Spring JDBC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/) support. First of all you need to setup a database. Then, you can retrieve the rows and process them appropriately.

You should have a table, where you have rows and a column is filled with like `/admin/**` and `/db/**`. The other column should be filled with role access information. After that, by following the tutorial, you should retrieve these rows. Let's assume you have following entity class:

```
class Matcher {
   public String name;
   public String roleInfo;
}
```

Then, you can iterate over the `Matcher` entities for configuration:

```
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll();

    for (Matcher matcher : matchers) {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(matcher.name).access(matcher.roleInfo);
    }
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                    // ...
            .formLogin();
```

Comment: I already have a database setup. How can I assign value to antMatchers from database instead of hard code in class. If I am missing something please tell me what kind of database setup you want me to do.

Comment: so while server starts I have to read database value and then iterate?

Comment: protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {} function works when user loged or app up server??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case for a role I have several routes assigned. Someone may need it. It should be noted that I take as a reference the @mtyurt answer.
The way I solved it was as follows:

```
List<Role> roles = roleRepository.findAll();
for (Role role : roles
        ) {
    List<Page> pages = pageRepository.findPagesPerRole(role.getId());
    List<String> pageslist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Page page : pages
         ) {
        pageslist.add(page.getUrl());
    }
    String[] authorities = pageslist.toArray(new String[0]);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(authorities).hasAuthority(role.getAuthority().toString());
}
```

I have a `table` where I keep the *routes* and another where I keep the `roles`. In the roles I can assign pages to you, and a page can be in several roles, so a `many-to-many` table is generated. From SQL I got the list of routes that are assigned to a role. That's why I do two cycles. Then finally to http I assign an array of `strings` and the name of the role.