# Permission to Access JSP Page Using Useroles in Spring Boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I want to restrict some **JSP** pages  according to the **UserRole** in my spring boot app

for this i have seen so many examples like:-

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

but my problem is i cant hardcode the **UserRoles** like ADMIN or USER because i have new user roles created in different occasions so i can't hardcode the exact user-roles.i have the information about the user-roles that can access a list of jsp pages in my database and here iam using spring security and iam newbie to spring boot and spring security.

**edit**

my config class is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
     CustomAuthHandler customAuthenticationHandler;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        System.out.println(1);
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    CustomAuthHandler authenticationHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthHandler();
    }

    /*@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring()

                            .antMatchers("/edu/assets/**");
    }
    */
     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests() 
                        .antMatchers("/edu/**","/Login**","/UserSignUP","/organization**","/email_availablity").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/Login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/index1",true).failureHandler(customAuthenticationHandler).permitAll()
                        .and()
                    .logout()
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .csrf().disable();

        }

     @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        }



}
```

Comment: you can define the roles in application.properties file and inject them to your class.

Comment: @Juvanis new user roles can created so i cant predict coming roles

Comment: @arsulhuk, your above code snippet contains in a function which is annotated with `@Bean`. So, this is initialized when you up your service.

Comment: @sunkuet02 sorry friend i dont get t.plzz explain with a example

Comment: You need to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704593/spring-security-authorize-requests-value-from-database, to get the roles and patterns from database

Comment: @arsulhuk, how are you authenticating users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are validating api not `.jsp` pages.

[@Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotation is used in java file to configure your application instead of xml configuration. From the `spring`'s official doc:

> Indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be
>   processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and
>   service requests for those beans at runtime.

So, When you annotated a class with `@Configuration` the methods are executed just for a time at the very beginning when you start your program. That's why you can't dynamically check `UserRoles` from the below method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // inner codes
}
```

So, you have to hard coded(in your `.java` file or `.properties` file) if you want to authorize from that method.

**The Solution**

I have noticed that you are using `UserDetailsService` for the login purpose. You can modify the `loadUserByUsername(String username)` method and dynamically check authorization for users.

Steps:

- Store the complete user information: login, password and Roles in a database. For this you need 3 Tables: 1. `User`, 2. `Roles` and 3. `User_Roles`. Each time while login, you need to set the `UserRoles`(roles are read from database) to the `UserInfo` object.
- Then you can add a [Interceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)(as a url filter) to your project to check each api(or url) whether Logged user is authorized for the api or not. For this, you can query database with the username for the roles and compare with the requested uri.

Comment: thanks for your response, but i have also use loadUserByUsername(String username)  methode. plzz check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704593/spring-security-authorize-requests-value-from-database

Comment: I think your urls are hardcoded for specific roles not users. And, I have given solution of that scenario. in the second step of the solution, you can validate urls for users with specific roles, dynamically

Comment: @arsulhuk, I have seen this. But my solution is better than that, and most of the persons will suggest my solution, I think. And it is better to store user roles rather than the url path in db.

Comment: @arsulhuk, we are a community so, nothing to disturb.

Comment: k friend then can you give some example for me?

Comment: just remember some time new user roles can create

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150829/discussion-between-arsul-huk-and-sunkuet02).

Comment: how to access session scoped object variable in inteceptor??

Comment: you can see the link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283450/access-session-scoped-variable-in-spring-interceptor

Comment: can u help me??

Comment: First you have to set your session and then needs to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found a answer...

1.Create an interceptor class in your spring boot

```
public class MyCustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{

        //unimplemented methods comes here. Define the following method so that it     
        //will handle the request before it is passed to the controller.

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse  response){
        //your custom logic here.(for request validating)
            return true;
        }
    }
```

2.Define a configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyCustomInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

thats all now your requests will pass through the logic defined under preHandle() method of MyCustomInterceptor before pass through controller